# How to fix transparency in product sliders / featured products on home page?

Tags: shortcode, css, woocommerce-offtopic

As shown in the below image, I am hoping someone can tell me how to fix the transparency of the product boxes.

I am using Avada. I used the default woocommerce shortcode to put the "featured products" on the homepage like so. But for some reason when I make the container for the shortcode transparent, part of the product box is transparent as well??

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Reed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just have to apply white (#FFFFFF) background-color to the slider item because by default it has **transparent background color**.

Please use below CSS

```
.owl-item {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Please note that this should be placed at the bottom so it gets high priority.

If it does not work can you please provide link of your page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Find out that class in which you want to add background color. 
You can find out it by Inspect Elements. Then find out parent class or id, In case if it affect other portion of website.

Then put css in child theme of avada or custom css of theme option like

.featured-class .your class
{
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

That's all if you are still having problem send me your web url.

Cheers